# Does anyone know if there is a limitation on the size of the file BitmapFactory.decodeFile can decode?

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I use the following code.  With large image files it returns null, small ones display. Does anyone know if there is a size limitation with BitmapFactory.decodeFile?

```
            File imgFile = new File(path);              
            if(imgFile.exists())
            {       
                Bitmap myBitmap=null;

                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                 

                ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);                                                                                                       
                if(myBitmap!=null) {                    

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NULL",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO FILE",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: There shouldn't be limitations from what I have seen in documentation, some threads will need their own thread though to keep your ui from stalling on load.

Comment: So this should run in it's own thread?

Comment: I would recommend sending bitmap decoding to an AsyncTask. Yazan might be right about heap size but I am not sure how Android handles memory allocation during bitmap decoding, and the image would have to be really large and likely high res to run into heap issues.

Comment: You should resize the file while decoding. If it is a jpg (you did not tell what kind of file it was) then to become a bitmap you would easyly need more then twenty times as much memory as original file size.

Answer (score 0):

how large is it? how many MBs?

do you get an OutOfMemoryException because each mobile app have specific amount of memory (heap size) and a large bitmap might exceed this limit, so u get a null

EDIT:
unless the big bitmap by chance, is corrupted of some weird format that the app could not decode? try another large bitmap

Comment: It's about 3mb. I had it in a try catch block no exceptions. It's not corrupted I opened it in other apps and tested with other files. It returns null in the emulator and on a Samsung S4.

Comment: well, according to documentation "Returns
the resulting decoded bitmap, or null if it could not be decoded."
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)

Comment: what do u mean by other apps? like PC apps or mobile apps? because sometimes you might get image opens on PC but not OK for mobile ...

Comment: The image files I am using open and display in other mobile apps.

Comment: well, thats all i can think of for this, if i were you i will get another bmp file same size and try it, you need to trace this to narrow the possibilities until u get the reason

Comment: a good trick i do sometimes, just open the image in msPaint or other editors, and Save it, then re use it in the app, clean the project or rename the file to ensure you get the updated image, see what u get

Comment: I found out what's going on, I added imgFile.length(); the files which were created by the camera app were zero length.

Answer (score 0):

From experience there is a limit and when you hit that resolution limit for openGL you will see the following type of error message:

```
Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4128x2322, max=4096x4096)
```

You may also get a OutOfMemoryException error like many have noted.

First of all you should do this:

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
final int width = options.outWidth;
final int height = options.outHeight;
```

Now that you have the width and height, it's time to make an intelligent decision about how to rescale it.

I would at this point look at the full code example (really only two methods to copy/paste) from Google at [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).